# How Can I Get the Controller to Register the Value of Votes to the Database?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm desperately trying to find out a solution towards solving this feature, but I haven't really got any useful help anywhere so far.

I'm working on a ASP.NET Framework MVC project, where I try to implement a simple rating feature for a Quiz class. But I'm kind of lost when it comes to the AJAX part and the Controller. 
I can't figure it out how to implement this so every votes related to a specific Quiz gets registered in the Notification table.

I created a Notification class inside Model to store the results of Votes:

```
  public class Notification
{
    public int  Id { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    public Quiz Quiz { get; set; }        

    public int UpVoteCount { get; private set; }

    public int DownVoteCount { get; private set; }

    public int Score => UpVoteCount - DownVoteCount;

    public void UpVote()
    {
        UpVoteCount++;
    }

    public void DownVote()
    {
        DownVoteCount++;
    }
}
```

Then in the folder under Controller/API/QuizsController.cs I have implemented this action method, which I'm unsure of it's implementation. I'm kind of lost in this part! :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Vote(int id)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var quiz = _context.Guizzes.Single(m => m.Id == id && m.AuthorId == userId); 

        var notification = new Notification
        {
            Quiz = quiz, UpVote, DownVote, Score
        };
        _context.SaveChanges(); // save to the database
        return Ok();
    }
```

Then in the View I created MyQuiz.cshtml file and in there I have implemented the below html and AJAX code, but again this part certainly lacks some basic constructions to connect the controller to register the votes in the database.:

```
    @model IEnumerable<VikingNotes.Models.Quiz>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-/rXc/GQVaYpyDdyxK+ecHPVYJSN9bmVFBvjA/9eOB+pb3F2w2N6fc5qB9Ew5yIns" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="quizs  verOffset7">
    @foreach (var quiz in Model)
    {
        @*<li> @quiz.Creation - @quiz.Author.UserName </li>*@

        <li>  
                <!-- Star Rating with font awesome-->
               <div class="rating-star ">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    }
                </div>   
   <!-- up-down arrow with font awesome-->
            <div class="article">
                    <a href="voteUp" i class='fas fa-caret-up' style='font-size:40px;color:darkgrey'></a> <br>
                    <a href="votedown" class='fas fa-caret-down' style='font-size:40px;color:darkgrey'></a>
             </div>  


        </li>
    }
</ul>

@section scripts
{

<script>    
        jQuery(function ($) {

            // Hook up our vote handlers
            $("a.vote").live('click', voteClick);

            function voteClick(event) {
                var voteLink, voteType, item, itemId;

                // Regardless of the below, we handle the event, so "consume" it
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();

                // Get the anchor element, wrapped in a jQuery instance
                voteLink = $(this);

                // See if the vote has already been done or is in progress
                if (voteLink.hasClass('done') || voteLink.hasClass('inprogress')) {
                    // Ignore the click, possibly tell the user why
                    return;
                }

                // Get the vote type
                voteType = voteLink.hasClass('up') ? 'up' : 'down';

                // Get the item we're voting on
                item = voteLink.closest('.article');

                // Get its ID
                itemId = item.attr('data-itemid');

                // If we didn't get an ID...
                if (!itemId) {
                    // ...report error
                    return;
                }

                // Mark "in progress" and initiate the vote; action continues
                // in our callbacks below
                voteLink.addClass('inprogress');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'savevote',
                    data: { itemId: itemId, voteType: voteType },
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: votePostSuccess,
                    error: votePostError
                });

                // Called when the POST is successful
                function votePostSuccess(response) {
                    // The POST worked
                    voteLink.removeClass('inprogress');

                    // Did things work on the server?
                    if (response === "ok") { // Or whatever
                        // Yes, the vote was successfully recorded
                        voteLink.addClass('done');
                    }
                    else {
                        // Report an error to the user, the server couldn't record the vote
                    }
                }

                // Called when the POST fails for some reason (HTTP errors)
                function votePostError(xhr, statusText, err) {
                    // Not in progress anymore
                    voteLink.removeClass('inprogress');

                    // Report error to user
                }
            }
        });

</script>

}
```

The Quiz Model looks like this:

```
   public class Quiz
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId{ get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(Int32.MaxValue)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Creation { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable Genres { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried another approach:
I tried to adopt this tutorial [https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Awesome-Rating-System.html][1]
with my project, but I couldn't get any results. I applied the instructions on the link and I downloaded the libraries and added to the project.

Please, some helpful souls!
(I've to add that it's my first project with mvc, razor and AJAX)

Comment: Where's voteClick called from?

Comment: That is Click Event that needs to be hooked to the .live event. That is missing piece that I couldn't figure out. I havn't implemented it anywhere. Cause I'm not sure how it should looks like and where to be placed.

Comment: So you want it where you click on a star and that rating is sent to the controller? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I edited my code under cshtml, where I added a up/down arrow(fa-caret-up). I rather would like those to be clicked.

Comment: See my answer below. Pretty sure that should be it

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is simply send the star rating to the controller. You can do the following.

```
           @for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
           {
               <a onclick"javascript: voteClick(@i, //ID of the quiz)">
                   <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
               </a>
           }
```

That should send the vote rating and the id of the quiz to the function. From there you can simply use an ajax post to post it to the controller method.

EDIT: Note that you will need to change the parameters of your javascript function to:

```
           function voteClick(vote, id)
           {
                //Function stuff
           }
```

Comment: What about the Notification.cs controller? Don't I need for that to be used?

Comment: @user10489212 Why would that need to be used. All you'll be doing is sending the data to the database?